# How to fix the error "comparison between pointer & integer"?

Tags: c

I have been trying to compare a structure variable and a string variable. But I am getting this error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    struct details {
        char number[20];
    } det[10];

    int inp, i=0;
    char aad; 
    int b;
    puts("Give The Number To Display The Pass Status");
    scanf("%s", &aad);

    for(b=0;b<i;b++)
    {
        if(det[i].number==aad)
        {
            printf("Hello");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Pls try to fix my error

Comment: `det[i].number` is a char array, which will be converted to a pointer in your if statement. What do you want to compare? You can;t compare a char to a string. You can only compare a char to a char, e.g. `det[i].number[0]==aad`

Comment: A `char` is not a string. You can't compare strings with integers using `==`. You don't initialize the array `det`. And so on. Now's the time to pick up a C programming book. You simply can't do programming by trial & error.

Comment: Please, clarify what is the current behavior and the expected one. For example, I guess the program crashes, as you are storing a string in  a single char `char aad; scanf("%s", &aad);`. What is `number` (it is unitialized)? And what does "comparing a string and a number" mean?

Comment: This is not related to your current problem, but `i` is always `0` here and your `for` loop will not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

after you look in the comments this will be the answer

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SIZE 20 // add size for aad

int main()
{

    struct details {
        char number[20];
    } det[10];

    int inp, i = 0;
    char aad[SIZE]; // must be array (can be with pointer, use malloc)
    int b;
    puts("Give The Number To Display The Pass Status");
    scanf("%s", &aad);

    for (b = 0; b < i; b++)
    {
        if (strcmp(det[b].number, aad) == 0) // strcmp to compare strings
        {
            printf("Hello");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```